# C++ pimpl avoiding void*

Tags: c++, c++11, pimpl-idiom

Assume I have a library that I want to hide. In that library, there is a function called "fun"

```
//Both class1 and class2 are defined in the library I want to hide
class1 fun(class2 P)
```

I am creating pimpl for class1 and class2 now.
***How should I implement the function "fun"?***
The code for class1_pimpl and class2_pimpl is below

```
//class1_pimpl.hpp
class class1_pimpl
{
  public:
    class1_pimpl(int value);
    ~class1_pimpl();

  private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl_;
};

//class2_pimpl.hpp
class class2_pimpl
{
  public:
    class2_pimpl(int value);
    ~class2_pimpl();

  private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl_;
};
```

I can only figure out if the function is only related to one class, such as

```
int fun_simple(class1 c, int i)
```

The way I solve the fun_simple is like below:

```
//class1_pimpl.cpp
class class1_pimpl::Impl
{
  public:
    Impl(int value)
      : value_ {value}
    {}

    int fun_simple(i)
    {
      return value_ + i;
    }

  private:
     int value_;

};

class1_pimpl::class1_pimpl(int value)
  : pimpl_{new Impl(value)}
{}

class1_pimpl::~class1_pimpl()
{}

int class1_pimpl::fun_simple(int i)
{
  return pimpl_->fun_simple(i);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If `fun` is a non-member function that works with only the public interfaces of `class1` and `class2`, you need to make sure that the `pimpl` versions also support those interfaces.

Comment: Also, using `unique_ptr` with does not obviate the need to define the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator.

Comment: It isn't clear where the probem lies. Are you getting any compiler errors?

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that functions in C++ should be member functions. That's clear from your "implementation" of `int fun_simple(class1 c, int i)` as `int class1_pimpl::fun_simple(i)`. There's no need for that. C++ has free functions. `int fun_simple(class1 c, int i)` is a perfectly fine definition as-is.

One thing you do want to change is `int fun_simple(class1 const&c, int i)`. This means the class doesn't need to be copied. In turn, you don't need to have the copy constructor available. And *that* means that you might be able to just forward-declare `class1;`. You don't even need a `pimpl` for this!
Instead, in your header you just provide a `std::unique_ptr<class1> makeClass1(/* your args*)`.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the function should construct the return value using a public constructor. Then you don't need any elevated access to that class and either delegate to member or make it a friend of the first one.

If the classes are so tied together that using a private constructor is preferable, you can always make the function a friend of `class2`.

To avoid needing the definition of `class2_pimpl`, create a private constructor in `class2` that will take care of constructing it and filling it in. Doing it in a constructor will be more reliable either way.

On a side note, does fun_simple really need a copy of `class1`? If not, it should be taking a const reference. Especially since copying a class with pimpl involves allocation and allocations are rather slow.